# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Conditional Row Formatting

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, ssrs-2012, conditional-formatting, reportbuilder3.0

```
=IIF(Fields!statusID.Value = "In Progress", "Gold", "Silver"), IIF(Fields!statusID.Value = "Rejected", "Red", "Silver"), IIF(Fields!statusID.Value = "Completed", "Green", "Silver"), IIF(Fields!statusID.Value = "Archived", "Blue", "Silver")
```

The above script is an effort of creating a conditional effect on rows in a report that I am building. The idea is of course to have the entire row of 13 columns to show a different color depending on the values caught from `Fields!statusID`

I have the condition set up under the properties of the report. My issue is when I put the condition on and run the report, I get `error: [BC30205] End of Statement error`. And I am unclear as to what this means and how to fix the issue.

Does it matter that the `Fields!statusID` is originally stored as a integer and then a `=Switch` is attached to it to produce a word?

Any help will be appreciated in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Instead of writing it as an IIF, I wrote it using the Switch Function, while replacing the characters to integers as it is stored in my database